# Lining up columns with HTML/CSS that have buttons

Tags: html, css, button, format, multiple-columns

Here is my current HTML/CSS/JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/3EBVD/.

Specifically, the CSS that I'm focusing on (although I guess the problem could be elsewhere):

```
#linkButtons {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50px;
    outline:2px solid black;
}
#defText {
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    width: 45%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#voteButtons {
    display: table-cell;
    padding:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    width: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

There are two boxes, the first of which is perfect and exactly what I need. The second one (the one with the buttons) is not lining up correctly and I can't figure out why.

Yes I have tried the float property which so far only screws up everything more...unless I'm doing something totally wrong.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The only problem is an extra `</div>` in your html.  Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/BQ49L/

Comment: Oh my god are you kidding me... Thank you thank you thank you! It's perfect!

Comment: Sure thing!  I can certainly relate -- I've spent more than my share of time convinced a problem was in my CSS when it was really in my HTML, or vice-versa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the way you want . I have fixed some html tags

```
<div id=voteButtons>
                            <button id=upvote onclick="modify_qty(1)">&#8593</button>
                            <p>
                                <input id="qty" value="0" readonly>%
                                <button id=comment>COM</button>
                            </p>
                            <button id=downvote onclick="modify_qty(0)">&#8595</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="one"></div>
```

this was outside the second-outline div
http://jsfiddle.net/3EBVD/3/